# Reformatting an improper date

Tags: r, date

Currently, I'm working through the Retrosheet data frame for RStudio and do not like the date format and would like to change it.

```
devtools::install_github("rmscriven/retrosheet")
```

Then I imported the data frame I wanted to work from

```
GL17 <- getRetrosheet("gamelog", 2017)
```

the data frame date vector is made YYYYMMDD just as such with no proper formatting e.g. `20170402` but I would like to change it to show for example as `2017-04-02` I have tried `as.Date(GL17$Date, "Y%d%m%")` which came back as

```
Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Which makes perfect sense. Is there another way to manipulate the entire vector easier than edit(GL17) which takes forever and usually doesn't work.

Comment: I've removed the dplyr and lubridate tags, which are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

"... **YYYYMMDD** just as such with no proper formatting e.g. 20170402 but I would like to change it to show for example as 2017-04-02 I have tried as.Date(GL17$Date, **"Y%d%m%"**) which came back as "

Its YYYYMMDD but you did "Y%d%m" which is wrong on two levels - a missing % and m and d in the wrong order:

```
> as.Date("20100331","Y%d%m")
[1] NA
> as.Date("20100331","%Y%d%m")
[1] NA
```

With the correct format this works:

```
> as.Date("20100331","%Y%m%d")
[1] "2010-03-31"
```

but notice that my mistakes above don't reproduce your error, so you must be doing something else wrong. Maybe your dates are actually big numbers:

```
> as.Date(20100331,"%Y%m%d")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

That always seems to give the same error that you are getting. Convert numbers to chars and try again:

```
> as.Date(as.character(20100331),"%Y%m%d")
[1] "2010-03-31"
```

Comment: I've tried this several ways but am getting this continually

Comment: `Error in as.Date.default(., as.character(GL17r$Date), "%Y%m%d") : do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”
11.
stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s", deparse(substitute(x)), dQuote("Date")), domain = NA)`

Comment: `10.
as.Date.default(., as.character(GL17r$Date), "%Y%m%d")
9.
as.Date(., as.character(GL17r$Date), "%Y%m%d")
8.
function_list[[k]](value)
7.
withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6.
freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5.
`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2.
withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1.
GL17r %>% as.Date(as.character(GL17r$Date), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: I have written in the date name for the vector several different ways with just the Date, "Date" GL17$Date, and "GL17$Date"

Comment: Op I figure it out, it just needed the mutate function fixed in.

Comment: `GL17 <- GL17r %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(as.character(GL17r$Date),"%Y%m%d"))
GL17`